# Trying to print a dictionary to file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, for-loop, tuples

I have created a dictionary called students, so for example when I say print students[Student00, Student00] I get ('111111100', 72, 40)} and so on for the other student names

I want to output the dictionary into a csv file with each entry in its own cell in the csv so Student00, Student00 would be in the first cell, then 111111100 in the next cell, 72 in the next cell and then 40 in the last cell. I have tried the below code and it did not work. It printed the key in the first cell and then in the second cell the values but I want each value in its own cell. How can I get this to happen?

```
with open('ur file.csv','wb') as out:
    for key, val in students.items():
        csv_out=csv.writer(out)
        csv_out.writerow([key, val])
    for row in students:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
csv_out.writerow([key, val])
```

This line says, write me out 2 cells, with `key` in the first cell and `val` in the second. If you want `writerow` to write 4 cells then you have to provide it a list of length 4. From your description, `val` is a 3-tuple. Try this:

```
csv_out.writerow([key] + list(val))
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. I didn't even realize.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('ur file.csv','wb') as out:
    csv_out=csv.writer(out)
    # then do for loop and write stuff...
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.